# Unable to add image in an nstableview cell?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsimage

I have tried this so far but on image is displayed in tableview.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSLog(@"Entered to create a new cell for table");
    // Get a new ViewCell
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"country"]) 
    {
         cellView.textField.stringValue = [[[AppConstants sharedInstance].CountryList objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"country"];
    }
    else
    {
          NSImage* img=[[NSImage alloc]init];
          img=[NSImage imageNamed:@"usa-flag.png"];
         [[cellView imageView] setImage:img];
   }
   return cellView;
}
```

How can I add images in a column.The images are small but there will only be an image in a column.Text will be in other columns.

**EDIT:** Do I have to make some modifications to the nib file ? I have only added a new tablcecolumn.My tableview is view based.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this just change your else block like this 
below-

```
  NSImage* img=[NSImage 
  imageNamed:@"usa-flag.png"];

//now set into imageview 
 imgView=[[NSImageView       
  alloc]init];
   [imgView setImage:img];

     cellView.imageView.image=imgView.image;
```

Comment: still not working.Do I have to make some modifications in my nib file as well? Do I have to add an iamgeview or imagecell to my table column in the nib file?

Comment: Yes in your nib file you need to add the imageview because it is view based table view

Comment: my table is view based not cell based

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this By removing the original cellview and adding Image and text table cell view.